# can't change kendo grid column formatting number from 2.666666 to 2.66 ( decimal placeholder 0:0.00)

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

halo guys i can't change format number to decimal placeholder (from 2.66666 to 2.66), i ready to put the fromat but it not change.
`

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: settingModel.ds_grid_dataSource,
        resizable: "true",
        editable: "inline",
        scrollable: "true",
        sortable: "true",
        filterable: "true",
        pageable: "true",
        height: "500px",
        columns: [
            { field: 'NRP', title: 'NRP', width: 80 },
            { field: 'NAMA', title: 'Name', width: 100 },
            { field: 'NAMA_PEKERJAAN', title: 'Pekerjaan', width: 100 },
            { field: 'AVG_AP', title: 'Nilai', format: '{0:0.00}', width: 50 }, //this is my column that i want to change format number
            { title: 'Pilih', template: $('#tmp_check').html(), width: 30 },
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

this is my screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrG0Z.jpg)

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What about `format: 'n2'` or `format: '{0:n2}'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your datasource, is AVG_AP a number? If it is a string then format will not work.

Either change the datasource so that the AVG_AP property is a number or template it to convert it from string to float and round to 2 decimal places:

```
{ field: 'AVG_AP', title: 'Nilai', template: "#:(Math.round(parseFloat(AVG_AP) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)#", width: 50 },
```

Comment: yes, AVG_AP is a string

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: Suggestion added.

Comment: can you help my other question to? here the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845450/cant-change-datetime-format-kendo-grid-from-2022-12-12t000000-to-12-12-2022