# can't change DateTime format kendo grid from 2022-12-12T00:00:00 to 12/12/2022

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have TGL_MASUK as DateTime type on datasource, but the output is **2022-12-12T00:00:00**, i want to change the output to dd/MM/yyyy.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: settingModel.ds_grid_dataSource,
        resizable: "true",
        editable: "inline",
        scrollable: "true",
        sortable: "true",
        filterable: "true",
        pageable: "true",
        height: "500px",
        columns: [
            { field: 'NRP', title: 'NRP', width: 30 },
            { field: 'NAMA', title: 'Name', width: 70 },
            { field: 'SUBCONT_CODE', title: 'Subcont', width: 50 },
            { field: 'DISTRICT', title: 'District', width: 50 },
            { field: 'TGL_MASUK', title: 'Tanggal Masuk', format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", width: 50 }, //this is the column that i want to change format
            
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

can you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `template` field and then `kendo.toString()` to convert the date to the desired format.
This way it should work:

```
{ field: 'TGL_MASUK', title: 'Tanggal Masuk', template: '#= kendo.toString(TGL_MASUK, "dd/MM/yyyy") #', width: 50 }
```